# Perl class closure

Tags: perl

I have been trying to create a closure inside an object as described on [perltoot](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/perltoot.html#closures_as_objects). I have copied it exactly, even copy & pasting it, but I am still able to access the object in the usual way, `$obj->('NAME')`. I am staring to lose my patience with it!

I am I misunderstanding something? I have been using perl for years for personal projects and have just started to get to grips with classes and OOP in general.

```
package Person;

sub new {
     my $that  = shift;
     my $class = ref($that) || $that;
     my $self = {
        NAME  => undef,
        AGE   => undef,
        PEERS => [],
     };
     my $closure = sub {
        my $field = shift;
        if (@_) { $self->{$field} = shift }
        return    $self->{$field};
     };
     bless($closure, $class);
     return $closure;
}

sub name   { &{ $_[0] }("NAME",  @_[ 1 .. $#_ ] ) }
sub age    { &{ $_[0] }("AGE",   @_[ 1 .. $#_ ] ) }
sub peers  { &{ $_[0] }("PEERS", @_[ 1 .. $#_ ] ) }

1;
```

Comment: `$obj->('NAME')` is how you're supposed to access the closure object.  A non-closure object would use `$obj->{NAME}` instead, which won't work here.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @jwodder: I believe OP is expecting to access `$obj->name`, but to have `$obj->('NAME')` inaccessible (i.e. "private" or "internal"). In which case, perhaps inside-out objects would be of interest? Although after he OP has studied a few possible variations on OO internals in Perl, I'd recommend using an existing OO framework, such as Moose.

Comment: I suspect the OP expected this statement on the page to be accurate: _"Nothing under the sun will allow anyone outside the executing method to be able to get at this hidden data. Well, nearly nothing. You could single step through the program using the debugger and find out the pieces while you're in the method, but everyone else is out of luck."_  If you can execute the closure directly (ignoring the fact it's been `blessed`) then the statement isn't quite true, now is it?  Unless you do some additional hackery, Perl lets you do anything to an object that the class' own methods can do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you're right Joe Z, I was taking what it said on the page as being accurate. I wish I had posted this question hours ago! Still a lot to learn about OOP.

Comment: One thing outsiders can't normally see are variables local to the package.  So, depending on the type of data hiding you're trying to accomplish, that may provide a path forward for you.  Or, just relax and don't worry too much about it.  It's perl, not C++.

Comment: @Steve: You really should bring this to a close. I doubt that you understand all you have been told, but you have raised many questions that other people identify with. Its not a situation that SO deals with well, but please come back and desccribe your frustration, or say which answers were most useful?

Comment: FWIW the often seen `$class = ref($that) || $that` technique is considered by some to be [an unfortunate cargo cult practice](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=147784).

Answer (score 4):

For a piece of software that is intended for teaching purposes this is a litle ugly. A lot of the obscurity is the methods after `new`. Something like

```
sub name { &{ $_[0] }("NAME",  @_[ 1 .. $#_ ] ) }
```

is opaque and unnecessary. The modern equivalent is

```
sub name {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->('NAME',  @_);
}
```

It is also debatable whether the `$self` should be the hash reference, as it is, or the blessed subroutine reference, whcih I believe it should be.

If I rename the hash reference `$data` (it has no name anyway except within the closure code) and the subroutine `$self` then maybe you can see something more recognizable? I have also added the appropriate boiler plater and some additional white space.

**`person.pm`**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Person;

sub new {

  my $class = shift;
  $class = ref($class) || $class;

  my $data = {
    NAME  => undef,
    AGE   => undef,
    PEERS => [],
  };

  my $self = sub {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $field = $data->{$fname};
    $data->{$fname} = shift if @_;
    return $field;
  };

  return bless $self, $class;
}

sub name {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->('NAME', @_);
}

sub age {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->('AGE', @_);
}

sub peers {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->('PEERS', @_);
}

1;
```

**`program.pl`**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Person;

my $person = Person->new;
$person->name('Jason');
$person->age(23);
$person->peers([qw/ Norbert Rhys Phineas /]);

printf "%s is %d years old.\n", $person->name, $person->age;
my $peers = $person->peers;
print "His peers are: ", join(", ", @$peers), "\n";
```

I hope that it is clearer. You can `bless` only a scalar reference, but while that is most usually a reference to a hash, here it is a reference to a *closure*, which is a piece of code together with the data it had access to at the time the closure was created.

Every call to the class's `new` method creates and defines a new lexical variable `$data`. Ordinarily that variable (and the anonymous hash that it references) would go out of scope at the end of the subroutine and be deleted. But in this case `new` returns a subroutine reference to the calling code.

It is up to that calling code to keep the reference that is passed. A call to any class's `new` method is pretty pointless if the returned object isn't kept. In this case the closure is deleted because nothing can access it any longer, and the `$data` variable and the anonymous hash are also deleted for the same reason.

*All* Perl subroutine references are *closures*, whether or not the associated data is of any use. This one contains an implicit reference to `$data` that will be maintained as long as *anything* holds a reference to that closure. All that means here is that the line

```
return $data->{$field};
```

will refer to the same `$data` as existed at the time `new` was executed, so the hash is persistent, and it can be populated and inspected by calls to the closure subroutine.

All the other methods do is execute the subroutine from the closure with a specific first parameter. For instance, the call

```
$person->name('trolley')
```

executes the `Person::name($person, 'trolley')`, which in turn removes the `$person` from the parameter array `@_` and calls it (because it is a subroutine reference) using a specific first parameter instead, and copying the rest of the parameter array. Like `$person->('NAME', 'trolley')`.

I hope this helps to address the right interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 3):

**Being a closure in itself does not prohibit access from external callers**, it merely makes the interface more obscure to make foreign callers have to do a few extra jumps to get the internal state.

However, the fact the internal state is only accessible by a closure means you can do certain things in the closure function that apply access controls.

For instance, you could look at the return value of `caller` within the closure callback, to make sure the person invoking the closure are on a permitted whitelist of classes.

Then to circumvent that, one has to dig harder to get their calling code whitelisted somehow.

For instance, you could make yourself appear to be in the same package simply by doing:

```
sub foo {
      package Person; #haha, hax.
      $object->('NAME');
}
```

And that will lie to `[caller]->[0]` about which calling package is doing the code.

When it gets down to it, there's not many ways you can reliably hide state in such a way that its **impenetrable**, and its *also somewhat disadvantageous to do so*.

For instance, by obscuring private access, **you make writing tests substantially harder**, and you make it harder for other people to use your code in tests, because a common thing people do in tests is tweak internal state in various ways to avoid putting dependence on more complex and uncontrollable things.

**And there are more than one ways to restrict access control to private values**

For instance, I've been known to use [Tie::Hash::Method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aMethod) to provide basic access control, such as, but not limited to:

- Warning / Dying when hash keys other than a predefined list were created / written to / read
- Warning / Dying when untrusted packages accessed internal state

And these techniques can help iron out code bugs too, not simply provide access restrictions, because it can help you refactor things and diagnose where legacy code is still using the deprecated interfaces.

Maybe this rather simple code could give some inspiration:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

{

    package Foo;
    use Tie::Hash::Method;
    use Carp qw(croak);
    use Class::Tiny qw(name age), {
        peers => sub { [] }
    };

    sub _access_control {
        my $caller = [ caller(2) ]->[0];
        if ( $caller ne 'Foo' ) {
            local @Foo::CARP_NOT;
            @Foo::CARP_NOT = ( 'Foo', 'Tie::Hash::Method' );
            croak "Private access to hash field >$_[1]<";
        }
    }

    sub BUILD {
        my ( $self, $args ) = @_;
        # return # uncomment for production!
        tie %{$self}, 'Tie::Hash::Method', STORE => sub {
            $self->_access_control( $_[1] );
            return $_[0]->base_hash->{ $_[1] } = $_[2];
          },
          EXISTS => sub {
            $self->_access_control( $_[1] );
            return exists $_[0]->base_hash->{ $_[1] };
          },
          FETCH => sub {
            $self->_access_control( $_[1] );
            return $_[0]->base_hash->{ $_[1] };
          };
    }
}

my $foo = Foo->new();
print qq[has name\n]  if defined $foo->name();
print qq[has age\n]   if defined $foo->age();
print qq[has peers\n] if defined $foo->peers();
$foo->name("Bob");
$foo->age("100");
print $foo->{name};  # Dies here.
```

Comment: I think the question was about understanding the Perl code that was presented, not *"How can I hide object variables from the calling code?"* It is more Perlish to allow you to anything you choose to do rather than be prevented by the language from "bad practice".